# How to control camera rig orientation with optically tracked pinch in A-frame?

Tags: aframe

I wanna replicate what [this guy](https://youtu.be/pW6nlLV88Zk?t=15) does.
Basically, you go back and forth from one corner of your room to another and rotate the scene when you reach the guardian fence.

https://repl.it/@tetegithub/aframe#index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-box id="box" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>

        <a-entity id="rig" rotation="0 0 0">
            
      <a-entity id="camera" camera look-controls></a-entity>
            
      <!-- *** -->
      
      <a-entity id="leftHand" 
      hand-tracking-controls="hand: left;modelColor:#E9967A;" 
      onpinchstarted="rig.object3D.rotation.x +=Math.Pi;"></a-entity>
            
      <!-- *** -->
      
      <a-entity id="rightHand" hand-tracking-controls="hand: right;modelColor:#E9967A"></a-entity>

        </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added "onpinchstarted" event in the left hand's tag in the hope that when I pinch with my left hand the camera rig will rotate. And it doesn't.I think I have to somehow work with the event listeners and handlers but all the docs I read look like they are written for the robots. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Done something similar, feel free to [check it out](https://github.com/gftruj/aframe-hand-tracking-controls-extras/blob/master/components/README.md)

Comment: @piotr Thank you very much! Refined my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I came up with a sort of a solution by dissecting [the example project](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/handtracking/).

rig.js

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('rig', {

  init: function () {

    this.bindMethod();
    this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('pinchstarted', this.onPinchStarted);
  },


//I still don't get what this thing does.
  bindMethod: function () {
    this.onPinchStarted = this.onPinchStarted.bind(this);
  },
  
  onPinchStarted: function () {
    this.el.setAttribute('rotation', {y: this.el.getAttribute('rotation').y + 30});
     },

});
```

index.html

```
<script src="rig.js"></script>
```

```
<a-entity rig>
    <a-entity camera look-controls position="0 1 0"></a-entity>
    <a-entity hand-tracking-controls="hand: left; modelColor:#E9967A;"></a-entity>
    <a-entity hand-tracking-controls="hand: right; modelColor:#E9967A;"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Now I want the rig to yaw the same amount the camera has rotated while I was holding the pinch with my left hand.

And I made it work after a while thanks to [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705697/how-to-control-camera-rig-orientation-with-optically-tracked-pinch-in-a-frame?noredirect=1#comment116248487_65705697).

index.html

```
<script src="rotator.js"></script>
```

```
 <a-entity id="rig">
        
        <a-camera></a-camera>

        <a-entity
          oculus-touch-controls="hand: left;"
          hand-tracking-controls="hand: left; modelColor:#E9967A;"
          rotator="rig: #rig"
        ></a-entity>

        <a-entity
          oculus-touch-controls="hand: right;"
          hand-tracking-controls="hand: right; modelColor:#E9967A;"
          rotator="rig: #rig"
        ></a-entity>
      
      </a-entity>
```

As web XR hand tracking in the Oculus Browser where I test it is still experimental and unstable I added touch controllers' grip buttons.

rotator.js

```
/* global AFRAME, THREE */

AFRAME.registerComponent("rotator", {
  schema: {
    rig: { type: "selector" },
  },

  init: function() {
    this.bindMethods();

    this.el.addEventListener("pinchstarted", this.onPinchStarted);
    this.el.addEventListener("pinchended", this.onPinchEnded);
    this.el.addEventListener("gripdown", this.onPinchStarted);
    this.el.addEventListener("gripup", this.onPinchEnded);

    this.rig = this.data.rig;
    this.box = this.data.box;
    this.box2 = this.data.box2;
    this.camera = this.el.sceneEl.camera.el;
    this.axisY = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
  },

  bindMethods: function() {
    this.onPinchStarted = this.onPinchStarted.bind(this);
    this.onPinchEnded = this.onPinchEnded.bind(this);
  },

  onPinchStarted: function() {
    this.trigger = 1;
    this.oldCameraAngle = this.camera.getAttribute("rotation").y;
  },

  tick: function() {
    
    if (this.trigger == 1) {
      
      var angleDifference = THREE.Math.degToRad(
      this.oldCameraAngle - this.camera.getAttribute("rotation").y );
      
      this.oldCameraAngle = this.camera.getAttribute("rotation").y;

      var cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    cameraPosition.setFromMatrixPosition(this.camera.object3D.matrixWorld);

      this.rig.object3D.position.add( cameraPosition.negate() );
      this.rig.object3D.position.applyAxisAngle( this.axisY, angleDifference );
      this.rig.object3D.position.add( cameraPosition.negate() );
      this.rig.object3D.rotateOnAxis( this.axisY, angleDifference );
    }
  },

  onPinchEnded: function() {
    this.trigger = 0;
  }
  
});
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/tete-github/a-frame-walkabout) and [the version](https://www.timatimak.eu/experiments/a-frame-walkabout/index.html) published on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Does the rotation work if you trigger it outside of the event listener?
I see you're referring to "rig" in onpinchstarted, does "rig" exist as a variable in that scope?

One solution would be to start with a helper function that does the rotation, then run it in the console to confirm it works. Then, attach it to the scene via a javascript instead of html (doesn't have to be a component, but it might be easier to reuse).

The docs are unclear if onpinchstarted would work vs pinchstarted https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/hand-tracking-controls.html#events_pinchended